# Would this type of design be scale-able?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, alu, latency

With current technologies within a modern system, we have pushed the limits of computations within the CPU portion of the system where it now exceeds that of the memory units. Moving memory is slow and costly and this trend grows as datasets increase in size. The bus between the CPU and Memory is very narrow and this creates a bottleneck as well as higher power consumption.

We can have a CPU perform 3-5 billion instructions per second where its base clock frequency is measured between 3-5GHz, yet when we have to fetch data from main memory across the bus to the system's CPU this is now orders of magnitude slower creating various bottlenecks.

Instead of having a single CPU with an ALU and an array of memory cells that communicate across the system's bus independently, what I propose is to couple both the ALU process and the memory unit into what I like to call a single ALU Memory Cell.

The I/O of this device has the following structure:

- Inputs:

  - Three single input bit lines.
  - A clock signal.
  - A 4-bit instruction opcode.
- Outputs:

  - The three input bits as a fallthrough output.
  - The three inputs after being latched to a single bit register (history).
  - The two output bits that the resulting operation performs.

Here's a Logisim image as a diagram to my ALU Memory Cell. This could easily be extended into a 2x2 array of cells to create a full memory module. The columns would be single bits to a word, byte, etc. And each row would be a word line as convention systems already implement.

[image: ALU Memory Cell]

With this kind of implementation design in hardware, this could allow for in-place calculations on data without having to move the data. This could reduce latency, power usage, and even cost.

My main question(s) of concern is, would this be scale-able and a viable proposal to the solution of reducing memory latency and power consumption within a system?

In other words, instead of having a single CPU that communicates to a memory bank via a single bus, would we be able to decouple and integrate the two into a single unit or device by merging these technologies where each memory cell has its own ALU. Here calculations can be done in place on a set of bits. Yes, there are 4 single-bit registers, a full 1 bit ALU a single 4-16 mux, and a 2-bit output register per cell technology. This might have the potential to reduce the amount of memory(data) transfers as calculations and instructions can be done in place without having to move the data. Instead, we would move the instruction to the memory banks.

Comment: "With current technologies within a modern system, we have pushed the limits of computations within the CPU portion of the system where it now exceeds that of the memory units". Where what exceeds what exactly? I've no idea what you're trying to say here or what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Finbarr the amount of computations we can do per second is in the order of Billions via a 3.GH CPU, however, the transfer of data from Main Memory to Cache to CPU is orders of magnitude slower traveling across the main bus with a limited bandwidth meaning that a majority of the time the CPU is waiting for data. This creates a bottleneck, and the transferring of data or moving data from one memory location to another is slow in time, and costly in power consumption.

Comment: Useful search term "PIM" or "Processor In Memory". See also ICL DAP, and http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/aries/course/notes/terasys.pdf and of course David Patterson's Berkeley IRAM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_IRAM_project

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3sEaINPBOE and this is where I got the inspiration from. I'm just looking at this from a logic - I.C. perspective.

Comment: Just another of those (occasionally) wonderful 80's or 90's ideas buried in the sands of time. Look at reconfigurable computing for something that has clung on longer in niche markets.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The same thing happened back then with the thoughts of A.I. programming and for decades it was buried without a thought, but now look where we have come with it since then... And now that it is being used more frequently and the demand to process large datasets more frequently has shown our current bottlenecks and limitations pertaining to time latency and power consumption where the moving of data is concerned. If we don't change our way of thinking in the design process, we'll continue to be bounded by the limitations of our current technology.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Barely skimmed the discussion. Just a note to the wise. But (1) Are you suggesting that every memory cell also be an ALU? Every one? (2) Get and use Neemann's DIGITAL program. Much better --- much much better -- than Logisim. And maintained, too.

Comment: Processors have almost always been faster than the available memory. Cache was common back in the 70’s. Thus your basic premise is not new. Adding extra logic to your memory incurs a cost of speed and size, so your memory has decreased by 16x, the speed by 4x (* factors pulled out of thin air!) and then you need to figure out how to arrange this logic dynamically to extract a usable benefit. Also consider that a major part of the processor instruction mix is moves, so the extra logic in ram isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar has been done with GDDR memory, but it turned out that this wasn't useful in practice outside very few narrow cases, and even those have vanished.

Graphics cards often had a dedicated XOR operation for rendering a cursor by inverting pixels, and those could additionally be addressed to rectangles by masking address bits.

For general purpose computing, CPU caches are far more useful, especially as some architectures implement prefetch instructions that allow you to load the next dataset into cache while the current one is being processed. The local cache has acceptable latency compared to the CPU clock, and on anything that isn't register-starved like Intel CPUs before the PentiumPro, the vast majority of calculations would be performed in registers without delay, and only the result written to memory.

Comment: Nice answer, but again even with cache hierarchies, we still have that bottleneck when trying to perform calculations on large datasets across the narrow bus. This would be a single memory cell that can be laid out in a 2x2 array creating an MxN matrix of ALUs on a single bit, thus being able to perform calculations in place. Now, the memory module in which this would be 1 of billions of cells would have controllers for addressing, as well device accelerators that could in theory learn what to do based on prior data sets. Making the memory module a smart self learning device.

Comment: @FrancisCugler, the Itanium ISA has explicit cache prefetch, including something called a "stride cache" where you can load matrixes column-wise. The problem with memory access is latency, not throughput, so if you instruct the cache to prefetch a certain area, it will submit all the read requests immediately, and typically the results come in faster than the CPU can process them. Where caches help less are memory-bound algorithms with unpredictable access patterns, but these wouldn't be improved by your proposal either.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add another answer after having slept on it: this is basically an FPGA.

Each logic element in an FPGA contains a lookup table combining multiple inputs, a single bit register that can be bypassed and a set of additional logic for clock selection, reset and routing of the output signal to other logic elements.

For algorithms that can be mapped to FPGA fabrics, this is indeed a lot faster as computation is completely decentralized, but typical FPGA clocks are a lot slower than CPU clocks as we need for the combinatorial logic to settle before we can take over the result into the register.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have ignored the presence of a register file in the core of the CPU. Even the simplest ARM Thumb-2 processors can access 13 32-bit registers without slowing down the CPU. So, the processor may only have to go to cache once per dozen instructions or so.

Make an array of processors like this and you have a typical GPU (graphics processing unit), and it is much more powerful than what you propose.

Thousands of system architects have spent billions of dollars attacking processor/memory bottlenecks and the scheme you suggest has been part of that mix. I'm sorry, but it seems silly to think that some youtube video holds the key to a revolution in computing. Spend some time learning about how modern processors work and why they work the way they do. Investigate the actual market for computing systems and you  will have a better idea of why systems have evolved as they have.

Comment: That's what I do, and I do understand how modern systems work. I'm 100% self-taught from C++ programming 3D Engines to Hardware Emulation all the way down to ISA and IC design. I never stated that a specific video had the exact answer. I just took information from that which inspired me to experiment with some simple concepts. The only thing I have available to me at the moment to build upon is Logisim and it has its own limitations. I was simply asking if it would be scalable in a practical way. There is a paradigm shift that is currently in the making. I was simply looking for some insight.

Comment: No, I didn't ignore a CPU's register file, I'm fully aware of that. I'm just referring to the movement of data across the bus that involves memory transfers (writes to different locations in memory). I'm not stating that you would fully do away with the CPU and main memory altogether... the CPU would still exist and perform instructions as it already does, but instead of moving memory (dynamically), we could instead have the CPU send the data and instructions to the main memory where memory could then do calculations on its own data independently and in place without having to move that data.

Comment: So instead of using the bus to transfer data to/from the memory, the CPU will spend all its time sending instructions instead.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Whatever. Good luck.

Comment: @Finbarr Not exactly, it would depend on the type of algorithm that's being executed. If it is a large data set such as seen in image and video processing, A.I. programming with neural nets and machine learning, etc. Then it would be optimal to perform the appropriate calculations on that data in place. Now, if it's just a few simple calculations on a couple of isolated data types, then no the process would be carried out in a conventional manner. It would depend on the data set that's being used.